# Как компилировать sass в css при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: css, sass

Есть json-файл, в котором содержится путь к картинке. Этот json импортируется в sass, sass, в свою очередь, записывает путь к картинке в переменную и передает ее в свойство background. При перезагрузке страницы данные в json-файле (пути к картинкам) могут меняться. Для того, чтоб css "подхватил" новые пути, мне нужно "компилить" css заново.
Вопрос: могу ли я компилировать файл sass в css при перезагрузке страницы?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью [php скрипта](http://blog.omgmog.net/post/getting-started-with-using-sass-in-your-existing-website/) (см. в конце статьи). При изменении sass файла он будет автоматически компилировать новый css  на сервере.

Comment: @Olga Moscow, я подозреваю, что строка

    $server = new scss_server("stylesheets", null, $scss);

На самом деле является враппером над

    sass --watch stylesheets:stylesheets

Comment: Через php - самое распространенное решение. Возможно, уже есть приложения для этих целей (и скорее всего), но мне не попадались, да и комфортнее через скрипт.

Comment: То есть, я могу компилировать sass в любой момент, когда мне это необходимо, если дам команду серверу? А как это влияет на производительность сайта? В этот момент сайт виснет, до того момента, пока не перекомпилиться весь css или для пользователя это незаметно?